# Vue send updated props to child after rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How to update PROPS after rendering in VUE?

**PARENT**

```
const myProps = [];
window.onmessage = function(data) {
  myProps.push(data)
}

new Vue({
  el: el || '',
  render: h => h(myComponent, {props:{myProps: myProps}}),
});
```

**CHILD**

```
<template>...</template>

export default {
  props: ['myProps'],
  ....
}
```

Due to window message comes later after myComponent rendered.. in this case no any updates, just got empty Array..
What the best way to listen updates props in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define `myProps` as data property in vue instance then run `window.onmessage` in mounted hook :

```
new Vue({
  el: el || '',
  data(){
    return{
      myProps : []
   } 
 },
  mounted(){
   window.onmessage = (data)=> {
       this.myProps.push(data)
   }
 },
  render: function(h){return h(myComponent, {props:{myProps: this.myProps}}}),
});
```

Comment: got Error : _[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'updatedPopup' of undefined"_ 

that means `{ props: { myProps: this.myProps }` 

where looks like `{ props: { myProps: underfined.myProps }`  in console

Comment: Try it out without `this`

Comment: has to be changed ES6 `render: h => h(..).` to function `render: function(h) {h(...)}` for **this** to be worked

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Boussadjra's answer, I would also recommend using a [state library such as Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html) which allows you to share state across pages.

But for a simple data share, Boussadjra's answer will work as well.

Comment: for simple cases he could use observable api

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answer if you want to interact with a Vue app from vanilla use a method.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    inc() {
      this.counter += 1;
    }
  }
})

window.inc = () => {
  app.inc();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Vue app : </h3>
  Counter : 
  {{ counter }}
</div>




<h3>Outside of vue : </h3>

<button onclick="inc()">
  Inc
</button>
```